# EF Generic Include with where clause

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to build generic method that would allow me to define navigation properties (each or them should be one-to-many relation - that being said, every navigation property I have defined is of type `ICollection`) that should be included in `linq` query. The problem I'm facing is that each Included navigation property should then be filtered based of `UserID` and `ValidTo` values. Models definition is similar to that bellow:

```
public abstract class SqlBase
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
}

public class Question : SqlBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string DateTime QuestionDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Answer : SqlBase
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string DateTime AnswerDate { get; set; }
}

public class Comment : SqlBase
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

What I am trying to archieve is a generic method that would allow me to only define which navigation properties I wish to Include in my query (in this case, both `Answers` and `Comments` properties from `Question` class). After navigation property is included, it should be filtered based on `UserID` and `ValidTo` properties, so the resulting query should behave in the same way as the query bellow:

```
_dbContext.Question
    .Include(prop => prop.Answers
        .Where(c => 
            (c.ValidTo == null || c.ValidTo > DateTime.Now)
            && c.UserID == 1
        )
    )
    .Include(prop => prop.Comments
        .Where(c => 
            (c.ValidTo == null || c.ValidTo > DateTime.Now)
            && c.UserID == 1
        )
    )
    .OrderBy(prop => prop.ID)
    .ToList();
```

Is there a way to define method which would automatically add this Where clause to every Included property defined in generic way? I am able to pass include properties in generic way (as a `string` or `Expression`), but I don't know how to then bind this `Where` clause to all of them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your assistance. However, what I am trying to achieve is to have master-detail report which would have all the questions, and then only answers and comments that are still not deleted and are posted by user with ID = 1. Because of that, Global Query Filters probably wouldn't be the best choice, since I also filter both of them by other criteria. Also, I would like to eagerly load related data because of the performance benefit.

Comment: `Where` and all LINQ operations are generic. You need to pass the correct `Expression` object. `c => (c.ValidTo == null || c.ValidTo > DateTime.Now) && c.UserID == 1` is already an expression. You need to assign it to a variable whose type is eg `Expression<Func<Comment,bool>>`. I'm not sure if you can use `Expression<Func<SqlBase,bool>>` too. For `ValidTo` though, you could use query filters to ensure only valid entities are returned. Which leaves only `c.UserID == 1` as a necessary filter

Comment: You don't have to use the *same* DbContext for an entire application. You can have different contexts, one for normal users that displays "active" entities and another for administrators/editors. If you use SQL Server, temporal tables can be used to only show "active" records and still keep older data

Comment: Maybe you need [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters)?